# Trying to get property 'is_admin' of non-object

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to build an authentication middleware for admin
but I got Trying to get property 'is_admin' of non-object

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Closure;

class Admin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{ 
    if(auth()->user()->is_admin == 1){
        return $next($request);
        }
       return redirect()->route('login');

}
```

and when I printed dd(auth()->user()) 
it returned null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`auth()->user()` **is returning `null`**

**Why?**

Because the user is not logged in.

So, you can modify your condition from:

`if(auth()->user()->is_admin == 1)`

To:

`if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->is_admin == 1)`

Comment: I tried your code, you're right it's not authenticated but I don't know why ?
I had sent the token in a header, after logging in but, it still  not authenticated

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::post('/products','productController@store');

}); 
this is my middleware group 
@Imran

Comment: What do you have in your middleware? Aren't you applying `auth` middleware?